# Angular 2 audio streaming to Spring REST

Tags: angular, audio-streaming

My requirement is to capture live audio (user speaking on microphone) in an Angular 2 app and stream it to a Spring Boot REST API.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any directions. Any pointers on the same will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be following links might be usefull
https://github.com/ShankarSumanth/Angular2-RecordRTC
[HTML5 rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

once you got the file convert to blob and pass to back-end.

```js
function uploadAudio(mp3Data){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var filename = encodeURIComponent('<somename>.mp3');
        fd.append('fname', filename);
        fd.append('data', event.target.result);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url to post data',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            //do something here on success
        });
    };      
    reader.readAsDataURL(mp3Data);
}
```

Comment: and spring boot where is it please !